# PHP8 - APCuIterator::__construct(): Regular expressions support is not enabled, please enable PCRE for APCuIterator regex support

Tags: php, apcu

I have upgraded our Docker images from PHP7.4 to PHP8 and now I am getting this error on every request:

```
APCuIterator::__construct(): Regular expressions support is not enabled, please enable PCRE for APCuIterator regex support.
```

We are using Symfony and it is making the call to `new APCuIterator()`. To reproduce this in isolation, I enabled `apcu` for CLI and then just invoked the constructor myself:

```
$ vim /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/apcu.ini
apc.enable_cli=1


$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > new APCuIterator('whatever');
PHP Fatal error:  APCuIterator::__construct(): Regular expressions support is not enabled, please enable PCRE for APCuIterator regex support. in php shell code on line 1
```

PCRE is enabled though, `preg_match()` works without problems.

---

Disabling APCu seems to fix the problem, but that's not a "solution":

```
# /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/apcu.ini

# extension=apcu.so  <-- comment this out
```

I am baffled as there is literally no match of this error message on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a version problem. APCu `5.1.17` which I had installed was failing.

Upgrading to APCu `5.1.20` fixed it.